# same program getting different output when debugged and run as script

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

for a sample picture, the value of start should be 7 after execution,
but gives output 0 when run as script.
when debugged, it gives correct result

```
def startdetection(start):
    i = 0
    while( i < coloumn):
        pixel = image.getpixel((i,start))[0]
        if pixel ==0:
            return
        elif i == coloumn-1:
            start = start +1
            i = 0
        else:
            i = i+1
    end = start + 38

startdetection(0)

print(start)
```

Comment: actualy, there is print statement in the program. i just didnt added it here

Comment: also, i am getting the correct output if i have no parameter in the function and declare start variable as global

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter `start` in your function and any global variable named `start` are different variables. Modifying the one inside the function does not affect the global one.

A better way than modifying globals in your function is to return the appropriate values from the function, using `return start`.